# QMultimedia::setPosition() не работает

Tags: c++, qt, mediaplayer

Доброго времени суток. 
Пишу mp3 плеер. Дойдя до прокрутки трека столкнулся с проблемой - при вызове метода setPosition(qint64) ничего не происходит

```
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename) );
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
player->setPosition(5000);
```

Пробовал `player->setPosition(5000);` ставить до `player->play();`, но результат не изменился. 
Благодарю за любую помощь

Comment: На сколько я помню, QMediaPlayer работает асинхронно, т.е. после вызова play() трек не начнет воспроизводиться в тот же момент, а существует какая-то задержка. Попробуйте добавить паузу междву вызовами `player->play();` и `player->setPosition(5000);`. Паузу можно добавить через `QTest::qSleep(250);` (не забыть подключить `#include <QTest>`)

Comment: Суть в том, что setPosition работает только тогда, когда QMediaPlayer::state = PlayingState

Comment: @goldstar_labs К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: @goldstar_labs Огромное спасибо за подсказку про state. Оказывается, подобных нюансов много (благо по запросу про state нашёлся qt example с подробным кодом). 
P.S. Мб кому-то будет полезно. У меня при первом запуске музыки state не менялся (проверял через сигнал stateChanged), но после нажатия на кнопку паузы всё исправилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и говорил @goldstar_labs, проблема была в том, что **state** у плеера был не `PlayingState`